# I want to delete a row based on a specific date in ClickHouse DB

Tags: python, airflow, clickhouse, directed-acyclic-graphs

I want to delete a row where date is '2022-09-08' the date is present but I am not able to delete it connected my clickhouse with python

```
table name :- repeat_day_by_last_120_active_cohort_v1
columns :- 'date','L120_active_cohort_logins','L120_active_cohort','percentage_L120_active_cohort_logins'
```

Code is as follows :-

```
client.execute(f'''ALTER TABLE repeat_day_by_last_120_active_cohort_v1 DELETE WHERE date = "2022-09-08"''')
```

Error message is as follows :-

```
clickhouse_driver.errors.ServerException: Code: 47.
    DB::Exception: Missing columns: '2022-09-08' while processing query: 'SELECT percentage_L120_active_cohort_logins, L120_active_cohort, L120_active_cohort_logins, date WHERE isZeroOrNull(date = `2022-09-08`)', required columns: 'percentage_L120_active_cohort_logins' 'L120_active_cohort' 'L120_active_cohort_logins' 'date' '2022-09-08', maybe you meant: ['percentage_L120_active_cohort_logins','L120_active_cohort','L120_active_cohort_logins','date']. Stack trace:
```

Comment: Wrong type of quotes. You need to use single quote, not double -- `'2022-09-08'`

Comment: No tried not working it runs but does not delete the row with that date ALTER TABLE repeat_day_by_last_120_active_cohort_v1
    DELETE WHERE date = date('2022-09-08')

Query id: 9e8f1c10-e69f-4bd0-ba9f-061a0a269376

Ok.

0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.005 sec.

Comment: because `ALTER TABLE ...  DELETE` is an asynchronous command (see the documentation), you need to append your SQL with `settings mutations_sync=2` to make it synchronous.

Comment: could u provide me with the full query so that I can try

Answer (score 0):

ClickHouse only allows using single quotes to quote strings while double quotes are used to quote identifiers, so the date you provide is considered as a column, and ClickHouse tried to find the rows which have a value in the column `date` equals to the value in the column `2022-09-08` which doesn't exists:

```py
client.execute(f"""ALTER TABLE repeat_day_by_last_120_active_cohort_v1 DELETE WHERE date = '2022-09-08'""")
```

Comment: please refer to the above comments as mentioned I have tried this it is running but not deleting the appropriate rows